# Laravel Custom Validation for multi-language application

Tags: laravel, validation, multilingual

I am using Laravel Standard Validation, but I want to customize it because I am using multi language in my application, so I have to customize the message.

```
      $rule_validation = [
        'phone' => 'required|max:20|min:6|regex:/^[0-9]+$/',
        'agree_promo_code' => request('promo_code') ? 'accepted' : '',
        'terms_of_services' => 'accepted',
        'aware' => 'accepted'
        ];
```

Now I want to write customize validation message for agree_promo_code

I know to write message for phone, but having doubt in agree_promo_code, terms_of_services and aware.
Can anyone help me out to resolve this issue

But please keep in mind about the language. Thank you

Comment: How are you doing validation? can you paste some code ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass second array to your validate function like

```
 $this->validate($request,[
            'phone' => 'required|max:20|min:6|regex:/^[0-9]+$/',
            'agree_promo_code' => request('promo_code') ? 'accepted' : '',
             'terms_of_services' => 'accepted',
             'aware' => 'accepted'
        ],[
            'phone.required'  => trans('validation.phone'),
            'agree_promo_code.accepted'  => trans('validation.agree_promo_code'),
            'terms_of_services.accepted'  => trans('validation.terms_of_services'),
              'aware.accepted'  => trans('validation.aware'),
        ]);
```

and inside your resources/lang/{lang}/validation.php file ({lang} is your language directory).

you can do something like

```
return [
      'phone' => 'Phone validation message',
      'agree_promo_code' => 'agree_promo_code validation message',
      'terms_of_services' => 'terms_of_services validation message',
];
```

So it will set your messages according to respective language.

Answer (score 1):

As you set your Language files for respective language
you need to create **validation.php** file under respective language folder
and add custom message for each field for each type of validation applied

for example if you have **name** field and validation check is **required**
so in your language folder's validation file you will write as below

```
    <?php
return [
  'custom' => [
    'name' => [
      'required' => 'O campo nome é obrigatório.'
     ]
    ];
```

rest all language check will be handled by Laravel itself while displaying validation error messages as per your locale language selected for session